# pureComputed properties using mapping plugin

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, viewmodel, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm using knockoutJS and I'm having some problems when using pureComputed properties.

This is my model

```
var LineItem = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable('');
    self.name = ko.observable('');
    self.description = ko.observable('');
    self.unit_price = ko.observable('');
    self.quantity = ko.observable(1);
    self.amount = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return self.unit_price() ? self.unit_price() * self.quantity() : 0;
    });
};
```

when I post the data using ko.mapping.toJS(LineItem) then it works, however, when I get the data from the server (in json format) and I use ko.mapping.fromJS(dataJSON) to build again the view model, it loads the amount field but it isn't a pureComputed value, so when I change the quantity value it does not update.

How can I make the field pureComputed again, once it is retrieve from the server by using the knockoutJS mapping plugin?

Comment: Have you looked at using the [`ignore`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#ignoring-certain-properties-using-ignore) mapping option?

Comment: I don't want to ignore a field, I just want to preserve the pureComputed after ko.mapping.toJS

Answer (score 0):

Since amount is part of the api data you could make your pureComputed separate from the amount:

```
this.amount = ko.observable(0);
this.amountComputed = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return self.unit_price() ? self.unit_price() * self.quantity() : 0;
    });
```

If that doesn't work for you, you could just make sure to recreate your amount pureComputed after calling fromJS.

Comment: I think this solution does not fit to me. I need amount to be computed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! 
I used the second argument (mapping) of ko.mapping.fromJS for rebuild my LineItem view model including the computed amount. I'm not sure if this is the better way to do this but it works.

```
  var LineItem = function(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.id = ko.observable(data.id);
        self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
        self.description = ko.observable(data.description);
        self.unit_price = ko.observable(data.unit_price);
        self.quantity = ko.observable(data.quantity);
        self.amount = ko.pureComputed(function() {
           return self.unit_price() ? self.unit_price() * self.quantity() : 0;
        });
     };



var mapping = {
  'line_items': {
     create: function(options) {
        return new LineItem(options.data);
     }
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(self.Model);
var unmappedJSON = ko.toJSON(unmapped);
$.ajax({
    url: 'myUrl',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: unmappedJSON,
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        var ignoreMapping =
        {
            'ignore': ["amount"]
        }


        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, ignoreMapping, self.Model);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    ...
    }
});
```

With **ignoreMapping** the plugin ignores this field and it keeps computable.